# Json array monthly data php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, format

I fetched data from database monthly based counts users. I got data in this format.
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[counts] => 1
[monthname] => April
)

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 1
        [monthname] => February
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 1
        [monthname] => January
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 2
        [monthname] => July
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 1
        [monthname] => June
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 1
        [monthname] => March
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [counts] => 1
        [monthname] => May
    )
```

)

But I need this in this format

Array
(
[February] => stdClass Object
(
[counts] => 1
)

[January] => stdClass Object
(
[counts] => 1
)

[July] => stdClass Object
(
[counts] => 2
)

[June] => stdClass Object
(
[counts] => 1
)

)
.
.
.
. and so on

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think `array_walk()` should work.

`$records` would be your array of objects, and you can change the ids with passing by reference. If you add an ampersand to the variable (`&$id`) that allows you to modify the array ids.

```
array_walk($records, function(&$id, $value) { 
    $id = $value->monthname;
});
```